# unable to boot desktop using ubuntu on usb device

Tags: boot, usb

very little tech experience, but have managed to install a new internal hard drive (the previous one failed) and have set the bios (successfully).  Now I need an operating system ... I downloaded Ubuntu via another desktop and copied it to a usb stick which I have now attached to the repaired desktop - when i'm at the boot device menu, I arrow down to *USB Device but nothing happens :(- can anyone help please?

Comment: Did you burn the ISO to the USB  following instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto  ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "nothing happens"? Does the bios say "no bootable media"? Does the screen go black? Do you just stay in the boot menu? Do you see any symbols or anything that could help us understand your problem?

Comment: thanks for your replies and thankfully am now sorted ... you're right, i hadn't burned the ISO to the USB and really appreciate your responses ... learning all the time! :)